# Android Studio: code has Duplicate Resourse Error, how can I fix it?

Tags: android, xml

I just started learning Android Studio.I'm working on building a Birthday Card App.
This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Happy Birthday,Seetha Hari!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
     <TextView
         android:text="From, Srinitya Suripeddi"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/birthday"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:src ="@drawable/birthday" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And i got :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Duplicate resources","sources":[{"file":{"description":"drawable/birthday","path":"/home/hse/AndroidStudioProjects/HappieBirthday/app/src/main/res/drawable/birthday.jpg"}},{"file":{"description":"drawable/birthday","path":"/home/hse/AndroidStudioProjects/HappieBirthday/app/src/main/res/drawable/birthday.xml"}}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [drawable/birthday] /home/hse/AndroidStudioProjects/HappieBirthday/app/src/main/res/drawable/birthday.jpg [drawable/birthday] /home/hse/AndroidStudioProjects/HappieBirthday/app/src/main/res/drawable/birthday.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Duplicate Resource error when i ran the application.

Kindly help.
PS: My OS is Ubuntu. I don't know if that makes any difference

Comment: You have a file with same name in your drawable folder name birthday.jpg
Please remove one and try

Answer (score 0):

It says you have 2 `birthday` resources. A jpg and an XML. So it fails because it doesn't know what to use.

Delete the one you are not using or rename one; if you intend to use SVG, then most likely the jpg because the XML would be the shape vector import of the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look -> You have a file with same name in your drawable folder name birthday.jpg

Please remove 1 and try again
full path is -> res/drawable/birthday.jpg